# Constructing estimators for a distribution

Tags: discrete-data, unbiased-estimator, asymptotics, estimators, consistency

I'm using the following probability mass function:
$$P[X=k] = \frac{2}{\cosh(a)+\cos(a)}\cdot\frac{a^{4k}}{(4k)!}\,  \text{ for } k∈N∪{0}$$

I have derived the following:
Mean = $a^4/4$; variance = $a^4/4$; skewness = $2/a^2$; kurtosis = $-13/4 + 4/a^4$

I have also constructed an estimator for $a$ by using the method of moments:
$a_1 = \sqrt[4]{4\,\bar X\,}$.

I need to show whether this estimator is unbiased and/or consistent. My idea was to use asymptotic unbiasedness, but I'm not quite sure how to do this.

I also need to construct two more estimators for a (one of them using an order statistic) and discuss their properties. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Because this is a decimated version of the Poisson distribution, you might review its theory for ideas.

Comment: I've looked into that but with the Poisson distribution the parameter is lambda, and in this case the parameter is (a^4)/4. So when trying to show unbiasedness and consistency I'm having trouble.

Comment: The parameter here, quite explicitly, is $a$.  If it helps, change "$a$" to "$\lambda$"!

Comment: Sorry you are right. What I meant was that the mean of the Poisson distribution is lambda whereas mine is (a^4)/4, thus when trying to prove unbiasedness I end up with trying to calculate the expectation of the 4th root of Xbar which doesn't make much sense. The problem is trying to show unbiasedness and/or consistency for this parameter estimate.

Comment: That's why it would help to review the *theory* rather than just the *results*.  In particular, you might be interested in the distributions of sums of these variables.  One approach would be to view your distribution as an equal mixture of four Poisson-like "distributions" with parameters $a, ai, -a,$ and $-ai$ (where $i^2=-1$). Another idea is to study the statistic $4\bar x$, which evidently estimates $a^4$: if it turns out to be unbiased, then (by Jensen's Inequality) its fourth root cannot possibly be unbiased for $a$.

Comment: Thanks. I looked into 4*xbar and it turned out to be unbiased using Jensen's inequality as you said. Does it follow to apply similar reasoning to show consistency as well?

Comment: If it's unbiased, then consistency follows merely from demonstrating it converges (in probability) to a constant as the sample size gets large.  That shouldn't be difficult to show, because you know the mean itself converges to a constant (due to the Central Limit Theorem).

Comment: I've also managed to show consistency. Thanks a lot for your help. MLE up next!

Comment: If you can answer your own question, please do so

Comment: Any thoughts on how to construct an estimate for parameter _a_ using an order statistic if there is no explicit solution in terms of _a_ for the quartiles?